# AWS Lambda function not allowing for endpoints with shared subdirectory

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have an API hosted on a lambda function on AWS API gateway. I have two endpoints, one that has been there for a while and a new one.

Old one: /bank

New one: /digital/bank

After the deploying the API, when I try to GET /digital/bank I get the response for /bank. Thoughts? I know I could work around this by naming it /digital/bank something else but want to avoid this work around.

Comment: The issue you are describing is not a limitation of AWS API Gateway or AWS Lambda. This is an error in your configuration somewhere. You need to provide a lot more info before anyone can help.